# How to find out which file is affected by a bad sector?

Tags: linux, filesystems, data-recovery, disk

Consider you've been informed about a bad sector like this:

```
[48792.329933] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed
[48792.329936] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
[48792.329938] Read(10): ...
[48792.329949] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 1545882485
[48792.329968] md/raid1:md126: sda: unrecoverable I/O read error
               for block 1544848128
[48792.330018] md: md126: recovery interrupted.
```

How do I find out which file might include this sector? How to map a sector to file? Or how to find out if it just maps to free filesystem space?

The mapping process should be able to deal with the usual storage stack.

For example, in the above example, the stack looks like this:

```
/dev/sda+sdb -> Linux MD RAID 1 -> LVM PV -> LVM VG -> LVM LV -> XFS
```

But, of course, it could even look like this:

```
/dev/sda+sdb -> Linux MD RAID 1 -> DM_CRYPT -> LVM PV -> LVM VG -> LVM LV -> XFS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional way is to copy all files elsewhere and see which one triggers a read error. Of course, this does not answer the question at all if the error is hidden by the redundancy of the RAID layer.

Apart from that I only know the manual approach. Which is way too bothersome to actually go through with, and if there is a tool that does this magic for you, I haven't heard of it yet, and I'm not sure if more generic tools (like `blktrace`) would help in that regard.

For the filesystem, you can use `filefrag` or `hdparm --fibmap` to determine block ranges of all files. Some filesystems offer tools to make the lookup in the other direction (e.g. `debugfs icheck`) but I don't know of a syscall that does the same, so there seems to be no generic interface for block->file lookups.

For LVM, you can use `lvs -o +devices` to see where each LV is stored; you also need to know the `pvs -o +pe_start,vg_extent_size` for Physical Extent offset/sizes. It may actually be more readable in the `vgcfgbackup`. This should allow you to translate the filesystem addresses to block addresses in each PV.

For LUKS, you can see the offset in `cryptsetup luksDump`.

For mdadm, you can see the offset in `mdadm --examine`. If the RAID level is something other than 1, you will also need to do some math, and more specifically, you need to know the RAID layout in order to understand which address on the `md` device may translate to which block of which RAID member device.

Finally you will need to take partition offsets into account, unless you were using the disks directly without any partitioning.

Comment: And, I guess, the progressive approach is to use ZFS or BTRFS and then just issue a 'scrub' of the filesystem. Then either the error sector is detected (and possibly corrected) or it is in unused space (and eventually gets later overwritten).

Comment: Also `dmsetup table` for mapping of device mapper devices (including LVs and LUKS).